# How to submit different forms from shared header partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling with finding a clean way to do this.

I have a `Campaign` model with a multistep form for creating it.

**I have a common header partial for all of the steps, and then each step has its own form that patches the Campaign.**

I want that the next button in the header submits the current step form in the view, but since it's in the shared header partial, I don't know how to pass the form object to it.

- I do not want to use JS for JS submitting, but I'd rather have a
  clean rails way to to this.

[image]

My header button:

```
 <% if @step < 6 && @step > 2 %>
              <%= link_to send("step#{ @step + 1 }_merch_campaign_path") do %>
                <button class="btn btn-accent" id="next-step-btn">Siguiente</button>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

*Controller:*

*My Campaign controller has a method for each step, and a submit method for each step like:*

```
  def step1
    @step = 1
    @elements = Product.where(tipo: "box", active: true)
  end

  def step1_submit
    redirect_to step2_campaign_path(campaign)
  end
```

Comment: is your intention to not re-render the header after each form submission? Are you submitting the forms using AJAX? What version of Rails?

Comment: I don't mind re-rendering the page. I'm using Rails 7. If I can do it with turbo-streams, better.

Comment: Rails 7 + turbo-streams implies a little bit of javascript! Maybe a single stimulus controller. But you don't want javascript. Maybe it's time to accept the benefits of a sprinkling of js in your ruby app, just as Rails 7 has done?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to to this with a clean way vía form HTML5 attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="Siguiente" form="step-<%= @step %>-form" class="btn btn-accent">
```

This way, I can still count on the HTML5 validations and good accessibility.